# How to concatenate the single and double quote

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem in concating the PHP variable , have a look below

```
$attributes .= ' href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('.$varpost->post_name.')"';
```

I want the output like

```
javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('about-us');
```

Thanks All.

Comment: you can escape $varpost->post_name; like (\'' .blah. '\'). Search google on how to escape strings in php

Comment: You should not use intrusive JS.

Answer (score 2):

Just escape your quotes inside the js function,

```
$attributes .= ' href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo(\''.$varpost->post_name.'\')"';
```

Comment: What if `$varpost->post_name` is: `"Mc'Donald"`? You must escape everything.

Comment: replace `$varpost->post_name` with `addslashes($varpost->post_name)`

Comment: They should be escaped in the first place, if he knows what he's doing.

Comment: What if `$varpost->post_name` is `<script>history.go(-1)</script>`. I know this is a crafted example, but it shows you that you must use the proper escape function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode`. Keep in mind that JSON-encode will only escape `"` (not `'`) so make sure your output HTML uses only `'`.

```
$js = 'javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo("' . $varpost->post_name . '");';
$attributes .= ' href="' . json_encode($js) . '"';
```

---

Ideally you'd use a more reliable way to generate the variable parts of JavaScript. In this case you would still use `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$attributes .= ' href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo(\''. $varpost->post_name .'\')"';
```

Comment: What if `$varpost->post_name` is: `"Mc'Donald"`? You must escape everything.

Comment: replace `$varpost->post_name` with `addslashes($varpost->post_name)`